# How to print Multiplication table by taking values from user using two do-while loops

Tags: c#, loops

I need help in this code it gives an error. Please  give appropriate answer to this question.. where I am just stuck and on which part of the code?

Using `Do-while Loop`:

```
Console.writeLine("Multiplication table");

int a;
Console.writeLine("Enter the Multiplication table no");
a = Convert.ToInt32("Console.ReadLine());

int b;
Console.writeLine("Enter the Limit");
b = Convert.ToInt32("Console.ReadLine());

int c;
do
{
     a++;
     int d = 1;
do
{
    Console.writeline(c+"*"+d+"="+(c*d));
    b++;
  }

while(c<=3)
```

Comment: This is incomplete code. Could you post the rest of it? There is no way this will compile or run.

Comment: Please edit your post to add exact error you are seeing.

Comment: Where is `c` initialised? Where is `c` incremented? Where are the closures for the to `do` statements?

Comment: Is it my eyes, or do I see some rogue " around.

Comment: "it gives an error" <- When asking questions here, always give the exact error message and related lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

As people have stated before, there are a few issues with this question for us to be able to provide a solid answer; incomplete code and not knowing exactly what the error you are receiving for a start.

However, from what I can piece together (making a few assumptions of course)

1. The big one is the non-initialisation of `int c;`. `c` must equal *something* before you call it. eg. `int c = 0` will remove that problem.
2. I'm assuming that your `do {} while ()` loops are fully enclosed? i.e.

   ```
   do 
   {
       do { something }
       while(something is true)
   }
   while (something else is true)
   ```

However, this seems a bit obsolete.

3. The function

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(c+"*"+d+"="+(c*d));
   b++;
   ```

doesn't really make sense to me. Should you be using `b` instead of `c`? If not, then does `c = b`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the second `while` statement so I have to guess you made it just after the first one, if not then you would get an Compiler Error.

You just delarated `c` but never set it to any value so `c<=3` is always true and you end up in an endless loop.

Answer (score -2):

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim counterR As Integer = 1
    Dim counterC As Integer = 1
    Do While counterR <= 10
        Do While counterC <= 10
            TextBox1.Text += (counterC * counterR).ToString + " "
            'TextBox1.Text += counter.ToString + vbCrlf
            counterC += 1
        Loop
        TextBox1.Text += vbCrLf
        counterR += 1
        counterC = 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Add an explanation to go with that code - code only answers aren't useful.